# An exception happened when converging configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

This is the response of `logstash -f logstash.conf`. I don't know what to do.

> Using JAVA_HOME defined java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2
> WARNING, using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a
> bundled JDK 2022-02-09T18:48:30.825+03:30 [main] WARN FilenoUtil :
> Native subprocess control requires open access to the JDK IO subsystem
> Pass '--add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
> java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED' to enable. Sending Logstash logs to
> C:/logstash-7.12.0/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
> [2022-02-09T18:48:44,793][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j
> configuration path used is:
> C:\logstash-7.12.0\config\log4j2.properties
> [2022-02-09T18:48:44,800][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting
> Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.12.0", "jruby.version"=>"jruby
> 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.2+8-LTS-86 on 17.0.2+8-LTS-86 +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
> [2022-02-09T18:48:44,879][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal]
> Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line
> options are specified [2022-02-09T18:48:45,593][INFO ][logstash.agent
> ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
> [2022-02-09T18:48:46,107][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections]
> Reflections took ۲۲ ms to scan ۱ urls, producing ۲۳ keys and ۴۷ values
> [2022-02-09T18:48:46,484][ERROR][logstash.plugins.registry] Tried to
> load a plugin's code, but failed. {:exception=>#<LoadError: Could not
> load FFI Provider: (NotImplementedError) FFI not available:
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not locate stub library in jar
> file.  Tried [jni/x86_64-Windows/jffi-۱.۲.dll,
> /jni/x86_64-Windows/jffi-۱.۲.dll]
> at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.getStubLibraryStream(StubLoader.java:450)
> at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.loadFromJar(StubLoader.java:375)
> at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.load(StubLoader.java:278)
> at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.(StubLoader.java:487)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
> at com.kenai.jffi.Init.load(Init.java:68)
> at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign$InstanceHolder.getInstanceHolder(Foreign.java:49)
> at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign$InstanceHolder.(Foreign.java:45)
> at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign.getInstance(Foreign.java:103)
> at com.kenai.jffi.Type$Builtin.lookupTypeInfo(Type.java:242)
> at com.kenai.jffi.Type$Builtin.getTypeInfo(Type.java:237)
> at com.kenai.jffi.Type.resolveSize(Type.java:155)
> at com.kenai.jffi.Type.size(Type.java:138)
> at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime$TypeDelegate.size(NativeRuntime.java:178)
> at jnr.ffi.provider.AbstractRuntime.(AbstractRuntime.java:48)
> at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.(NativeRuntime.java:57)
> at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.(NativeRuntime.java:41)
> at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime$SingletonHolder.(NativeRuntime.java:53)
> at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.getInstance(NativeRuntime.java:49)
> at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.Provider.(Provider.java:29)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
> at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider$SystemProviderSingletonHolder.getInstance(FFIProvider.java:68)
> at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider$SystemProviderSingletonHolder.(FFIProvider.java:57)
> at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider.getSystemProvider(FFIProvider.java:35)
> at jnr.ffi.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:114)
> at jnr.posix.POSIXFactory$DefaultLibCProvider$SingletonHolder.(POSIXFactory.java:289)
> at jnr.posix.POSIXFactory$DefaultLibCProvider.getLibC(POSIXFactory.java:318)
> at jnr.posix.BaseNativePOSIX.(BaseNativePOSIX.java:38)
> at jnr.posix.WindowsPOSIX.(WindowsPOSIX.java:134)
> at jnr.posix.POSIXFactory.loadWindowsPOSIX(POSIXFactory.java:173)
> at jnr.posix.POSIXFactory.loadNativePOSIX(POSIXFactory.java:142)
> at jnr.posix.POSIXFactory.loadPOSIX(POSIXFactory.java:93)
> at jnr.posix.LazyPOSIX.loadPOSIX(LazyPOSIX.java:38)
> at jnr.posix.LazyPOSIX.posix(LazyPOSIX.java:32)
> at jnr.posix.LazyPOSIX.isNative(LazyPOSIX.java:402)
> at org.jruby.util.io.FilenoUtil.(FilenoUtil.java:42)
> at org.jruby.Ruby.(Ruby.java:294)
> at org.jruby.Ruby.newInstance(Ruby.java:706)
> at org.logstash.Logstash.(Logstash.java:162)
> at org.logstash.Logstash.main(Logstash.java:69)
>
> See [http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4583>](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4583%3E),
> :path=>"logstash/inputs/file", :type=>"input", :name=>"file"}
> [2022-02-09T18:48:46,494][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to
> execute action
> {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main,
> :exception=>"Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException", :message=>"Unable
> to configure plugins: (PluginLoadingError) Couldn't find any input
> plugin named 'file'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the
> file input plugin resulted in this error: Could not load FFI Provider:
> (NotImplementedError) FFI not available:
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not locate stub library in jar
> file.  Tried [jni/x86_64-Windows/jffi-۱.۲.dll,
> /jni/x86_64-Windows/jffi-۱.۲.dll]\r\n\tat
> com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.getStubLibraryStream(StubLoader.java:450)\r\n\tat
> com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.loadFromJar(StubLoader.java:375)\r\n\tat
> com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.load(StubLoader.java:278)\r\n\tat
> com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.(StubLoader.java:487)\r\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)\r\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)\r\n\tat
> com.kenai.jffi.Init.load(Init.java:68)\r\n\tat
> com.kenai.jffi.Foreign$InstanceHolder.getInstanceHolder(Foreign.java:49)\r\n\tat
> com.kenai.jffi.Foreign$InstanceHolder.(Foreign.java:45)\r\n\tat
> com.kenai.jffi.Foreign.getInstance(Foreign.java:103)\r\n\tat
> com.kenai.jffi.Type$Builtin.lookupTypeInfo(Type.java:242)\r\n\tat
> com.kenai.jffi.Type$Builtin.getTypeInfo(Type.java:237)\r\n\tat
> com.kenai.jffi.Type.resolveSize(Type.java:155)\r\n\tat
> com.kenai.jffi.Type.size(Type.java:138)\r\n\tat
> jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime$TypeDelegate.size(NativeRuntime.java:178)\r\n\tat
> jnr.ffi.provider.AbstractRuntime.(AbstractRuntime.java:48)\r\n\tat
> jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.(NativeRuntime.java:57)\r\n\tat
> jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.(NativeRuntime.java:41)\r\n\tat
> jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime$SingletonHolder.(NativeRuntime.java:53)\r\n\tat
> jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.getInstance(NativeRuntime.java:49)\r\n\tat
> jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.Provider.(Provider.java:29)\r\n\tat
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)\r\n\tat
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)\r\n\tat
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)\r\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)\r\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)\r\n\tat
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347)\r\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)\r\n\tat
> jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider$SystemProviderSingletonHolder.getInstance(FFIProvider.java:68)\r\n\tat
> jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider$SystemProviderSingletonHolder.(FFIProvider.java:57)\r\n\tat
> jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider.getSystemProvider(FFIProvider.java:35)\r\n\tat
> jnr.ffi.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:114)\r\n\tat
> jnr.posix.POSIXFactory$DefaultLibCProvider$SingletonHolder.(POSIXFactory.java:289)\r\n\tat
> jnr.posix.POSIXFactory$DefaultLibCProvider.getLibC(POSIXFactory.java:318)\r\n\tat
> jnr.posix.BaseNativePOSIX.(BaseNativePOSIX.java:38)\r\n\tat
> jnr.posix.WindowsPOSIX.(WindowsPOSIX.java:134)\r\n\tat
> jnr.posix.POSIXFactory.loadWindowsPOSIX(POSIXFactory.java:173)\r\n\tat
> jnr.posix.POSIXFactory.loadNativePOSIX(POSIXFactory.java:142)\r\n\tat
> jnr.posix.POSIXFactory.loadPOSIX(POSIXFactory.java:93)\r\n\tat
> jnr.posix.LazyPOSIX.loadPOSIX(LazyPOSIX.java:38)\r\n\tat
> jnr.posix.LazyPOSIX.posix(LazyPOSIX.java:32)\r\n\tat
> jnr.posix.LazyPOSIX.isNative(LazyPOSIX.java:402)\r\n\tat
> org.jruby.util.io.FilenoUtil.(FilenoUtil.java:42)\r\n\tat
> org.jruby.Ruby.(Ruby.java:294)\r\n\tat
> org.jruby.Ruby.newInstance(Ruby.java:706)\r\n\tat
> org.logstash.Logstash.(Logstash.java:162)\r\n\tat
> org.logstash.Logstash.main(Logstash.java:69)\r\n\n See
> http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4583",
> :backtrace=>["org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline.(CompiledPipeline.java:119)",
> "org.logstash.execution.JavaBasePipelineExt.initialize(JavaBasePipelineExt.java:83)",
> "org.logstash.execution.JavaBasePipelineExt$INVOKER$i$1$0$initialize.call(JavaBasePipelineExt$INVOKER$i$1$0$initialize.gen)",
> "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:837)",
> "org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.instanceSuper(IRRuntimeHelpers.java:1169)",
> "org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.instanceSuperSplatArgs(IRRuntimeHelpers.java:1156)",
> "org.jruby.ir.targets.InstanceSuperInvokeSite.invoke(InstanceSuperInvokeSite.java:39)",
> "C_3a_.logstash_minus_7_dot_12_dot_0.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$initialize$0(C:/logstash-7.12.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:47)",
> "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80)",
> "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70)",
> "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:332)",
> "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:86)",
> "org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:939)",
> "org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)",
> "org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)",
> "C_3a_.logstash_minus_7_dot_12_dot_0.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0(C:/logstash-7.12.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52)",
> "C_3a_.logstash_minus_7_dot_12_dot_0.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0$**VARARGS**(C:/logstash-7.12.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb)",
> "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80)",
> "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70)",
> "org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)",
> "C_3a_.logstash_minus_7_dot_12_dot_0.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.agent.RUBY$block$converge_state$2(C:/logstash-7.12.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:389)", "org.jruby.runtime.CompiledIRBlockBody.callDirect(CompiledIRBlockBody.java:138)",
> "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:58)",
> "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:52)",
> "org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:139)",
> "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:318)",
> "org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:105)",
> "java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)"]} warning: thread
> "Converge PipelineAction::Create" terminated with exception
> (report_on_exception is true): LogStash::Error: Don't know how to
> handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for
> `PipelineAction::Create<main>`
> create at org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:129
> add at org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:57   converge_state at
> C:/logstash-7.12.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:402
> [2022-02-09T18:48:46,509][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] An
> exception happened when converging configuration
> {:exception=>LogStash::Error, :message=>"Don't know how to handle
> `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for
> `PipelineAction::Create<main>`"}
> [2022-02-09T18:48:46,519][FATAL][logstash.runner          ] An
> unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<LogStash::Error: Don't know how
> to handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for
> `PipelineAction::Create<main>`>,
> :backtrace=>["org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:129:in
> `create'", "org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:57:in` add'", "C:/logstash-7.12.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:402:in
> `block in converge_state'"]}
> [2022-02-09T18:48:46,527][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash
> stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
> org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
> at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:747) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
> at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:710) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
> at C_3a_.logstash_minus_7_dot_12_dot_0.lib.bootstrap.environment.(C:\logstash-7.12.0\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:89)
> ~[?:?]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I had to use java version 8+ instead of 17.